# how to explode [IMG] url[/IMG] in a sentence

Tags: regex

sorry for the confusion. I was succesful at preg split of [IMG]url [/IMG] to extract href link url out of it but i can't eplode the urls

```html
    $string = 'the cat ran after rat and dog chased after mailman.[IMG]http://thegreenlanterncorps.com/web/assets/GL_cover1_Marquee-1024x576.jpg [/IMG][IMG] http://thegreenlanterncorps.com/web/assets/GL_cover1_Marquee-1024x576.jpg[/IMG][MEDIA=utube]R8OlIZLnaGo[/MEDIA]';
$array = preg_split('/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/i', $string);
echo "this below is pregsplit  it works";
print_r($array);

print_r ($hulk5 =explode('$array' , $string));
```

here a link to what i'm working
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ad9c738fa3ec33790b65f952172a801c79b99049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can watch the test below

https://youtu.be/zXCutACuIv8

code is

```
$string = 'the dog was running and chasing cat but it gave up. 
[MEDIA=utube]R8OlIZLnaGo[/MEDIA]';


  $find = "[MEDIA=utube]";
  $indexof =strpos($string,$find);

  echo substr($string, $indexof);
```

For preg_match_all read the manual. This can split strings but your request is a bit outside the standard.

https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.preg-match-all.php

For strpos:

https://www.php.net/manual/tr/function.strpos.php

No matter what text you send with this code, it will only go to the part you want and return the part you want. With strpos you find the position of the word, which is quite logical.

Comment: wow, how did you know how to do this i've been exploding, preg splitting no stop but would of never guess this code. it does work

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b34e601a41c3ad26aacf78d825bc5317f2cdc3fe

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explode as your code, you must do substring and remove. This is basic way. Or create a function for this process. Please try substring to [IMG] and remove then split. Try and write.

Comment: sorry i was trying to extract something like this [MEDIA=youtube]F1U-MMGENRk[/MEDIA] out of a string like  $string = 'the dog was running and chasing cat but it gave up.[MEDIA=utube]R8OlIZLnaGo[/MEDIA]';

Answer (score 0):

```html
$string = "The text you want to filter goes here. http://google.com, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_m7NEDMrV0,https://instagram.com/hellow/";

preg_match_all('#bhttps?://[^,s()<>]+(?:([wd]+)|([^,[:punct:]s]|/))#', $string, $match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match[0]); 
echo "</pre>";
```